# Jasmine: how to run series of tests after an event has triggered

Tags: node.js, jasmine, eventemitter, jasmine-node

I'm trying to run tests on my npm module. The code below will work if I comment out either of the 2 `it` blocks, but times out if I leave them both in as below. How can wait for "ready" before running my tests (I'd like to add more but they too need to await "ready")?

```
describe("GA analytics", function() {

    var report = new Report(private_key, SERVICE_EMAIL, 1);

    it("should connect and emit <ready>", function(done) {
        report.on('ready', function() {
            console.log("test.js: Token: ", report.token);
            expect(report.token).toBeDefined();
            done();
        });
    });

    it("should get data correctly", function(done) {
        report.on('ready', function() {
            report.get(query, function(err, data) {
                if (err) throw err
                expect(data.rows).toEqual([ [ '5140' ] ]);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is happening because you create a new instance of the `Report` only once per test file, therefore the `ready` event only fires once and only the first `it` block in the test will catch it and process. The rest of the `it` blocks won't receive any more `ready` events, so they silently wait for it until Jasmine times out. The solution will be to create a new `Report` instance before each `it` block, which can be easily done with the help of Jasmine [`beforeEach`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown):

```
describe("GA analytics", function() {

    var report;

    beforeEach(function () {
        report = new Report();
    });

    // ....
});
```

[See the working example here on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D1hu9irMAd0SLdQVgFC7?p=preview) (open a "script.js" file)

Comment: Thanks. I had arrived at this solution in the meantime.